# Gstreamer - errorneuos_pipeline: no element "souphttpsrc"

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer, pipeline, gstreamer-1.0

I have installed gstreamer on Mac OS Monterrey, and I have also installed the gst-plugins.

```
brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly ffmpeg
```

I am able to run the following command and get output according to the documentation here. (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html?gi-language=c#gstlaunch10)

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=11 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Above commands successfully executes.

But commands with some of the pipelines, fail to run.

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm ! matroskademux name=d d.video_0 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=sintel_video.mkv
```

Command fails and the following result is logged in the console.

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "souphttpsrc"
```

- How come some of the pipelines are missing here since they are
  supposed to be installed using one of the four plugin groups?
  (`gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly`)
- How can I get the plugin `souphttpsrc` work?
- Is the plugin removed, deprecated or renamed?

Thanks.

Comment: Ask brew maintainers about that. Gstreamer offers their own official installer.

Comment: You can always build the gst-plugins-good repo locally and get the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with gst-plugins-good version 1.20.0 and is fixed with 1.20.1. Refer to https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/1007

I have opened a pull request - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/97969 to update brew formulae for the plugin to 1.20.1 (Merged 04/01)

gstreamer and gst-plugins-* 1.20.1 are now available for installation via brew.

Answer (score 0):

Missing souphttpsrc on GStreamer 1.20.6 running in a (Mac M1) Docker container based on alpine. **I had to explicitly add libsoup before gstreamer**. I would presume the same solution is worth a try on other platforms.

Full dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN \
  apk update \
  && apk add python3 py3-pip

RUN \
  apk add libsoup

RUN \
  apk add gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gstreamer-tools \
  && apk add py3-gobject3 gtk+3.0
WORKDIR /code
```

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue, but on the newest gst-plugins(v1.20.5) under my Mac Ventura (Apple M1)

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm ! matroskademux name=d d.video_0 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=sintel_video.mkv
```

the command fails

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "souphttpsrc"
```

v1.20.5

```
gst-launch-1.0 --version                                                                                                        
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.20.5
GStreamer 1.20.5
Unknown package origin
```

Comment: "Me too" isn't an answer.